# iPhone 3GS never goes into standby

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake

I have noticed a problem with my iPhone 3GS recently. It never goes into standby mode unless I turn on flight mode.

When I have phone mode on it will keep on running something in the background. I haven't been able to locate what it is. I have tried to close down all the apps which are in the quick access list. I have also turned of the `Location Service`, `Notification`, `Push`. I have practically tried to turn of everything, and nothing help except for if I turn on the flight mode.

Anyone know what the problem might be? This problem is seriously causing the battery to burn down.

**UPDATE:** ok it seems a simple reset to factory setting fixed it and returned it back to normal. Probably some bug in the iphone tick off when I updated to the latest iOS. Thus made iphone never truely go into standby mode.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Settings > General > Auto Lock?

Now that you've clarified the question:

The reason why I asked if you were in an area of bad coverage/weak signal is if your signal is weak then your battery will drain quicker.  However most people I know with iPhones would only get 24 hours out of a full charge anyway.  I usually plug it in at night and unplug it when I get up in the morning and generally it will last all day.  If you find your battery is draining too quickly for your liking you can do some of the following.

Turn off push notifications
Lower screen brightness
Turn off WiFi
Turn off 3G
Close apps which are running in the background

I'm guessing you haven't had a smartphone before and are used to getting a few days from a full charge.  Smartphones use battery much more quickly than traditional cell phones because of larger screens, more powerful processors and generally more usage.

Comment: it is not that reason, I mean even when it goes into standby the battery still drains like crazy

Comment: You said it never goes into standby.  Standby is when the screen is off.  How long do you get from a full charge?  Are you in an area of bad coverage?

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad for the poorly explaination. The problem is when I have fully charged my iphone, and I leave it be when I go to sleep. The day after the battery is down to 80%. I mean it can barely go on for a full day, (and I barely use it). When I go to `General > Usage` I see that the Usage time is equally to the Standby time. That's what I meant by it never goes into standby.

Comment: I already done all those things. And I have owned a smartphone quite some time now (2 years). The thing is that it normally last for couple of days with just having it on the standby. However now recently it can't even last for one full day. Even though if I leave it in standby.

Comment: Well if there are no applications running, the screen is black, you're not using it much and the battery is still, despite all of this, not capable of lasting a day, then I think it may need repair and we can't do much for you here.  You could try bringing it back to Apple, that's probably your best bet.

Comment: hey, I updated my question with the fix which solved my problem. All it needed was a factory reset. Anyway thanks for your tips.

Comment: No problem, glad you got sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I too have this problem. For me, the solution is to turn off and turn on the iPhone, and everything is again ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of your cell connection. The carrier probably tries to keep a connection alive, even while the phone is not in use. This is to ensure that when a call or SMS comes in, the phone will notify you about it. The battery will probably drain faster if the signal is weaker. Another process that may actively be running is the visual voice mail, which probably checks the carrier's servers for voicemail periodically as well.

The only way to stop these three services (phone, sms, voicemail), is to enter airplane mode. This is probably why you see an increase in battery life when airplane mode is on.

Comment: But this just became a recent problem. The signal bar shows full signal power.